# How can I find Phusion Passenger version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, passenger

How can I find my Phusion Passenger version? is there a command i can run from the terminal?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
locate passenger-config
/path/to/passenger-config --version
```

Or try searching your system's package manager if Passenger was installed from a package

Comment: It says: `cannot load such file -- phusion_passenger`. I installed `passenger` from [official repository](https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger/).

Answer (score 49):

You can use the following command to find out the current version:

```
passenger -v
```

Comment: You can find where your passenger command is stored, as it might not be in your path, by doing: `gem contents passenger | grep passenger$`

Comment: It says: `cannot load such file -- phusion_passenger`. I installed `passenger` from [official repository](https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger/).

Comment: Additional note, this command only works in the repository where you have installed passenger if passenger is not globally installed.

Answer (score 16):

try

```
passenger-config --version
```

Answer (score 9):

If installed from apt-get, you can't get passenger -v from a command line, however you could get from package manager:

```
dpkg -l | grep passenger
```

Which will return something like:

```
ii  libapache2-mod-passenger      3.0.13debian-1  amd64  Rails and Rack support for Apache2
```

You can than grab the version number from this with your favourite regex command.